# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I am new to openCV 3.0. I installed Eclipse cdt, followed the instructions given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html). Now when I build the project I get the following result:

```
18:15:16 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project DisplayImage ****
make all
Building target: DisplayImage
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "DisplayImage"  ./src/DisplayImage.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [DisplayImage] Error 1
```

I searched the /usr/local/lib where other libraries are present and I cant find these two files. What should I do now to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

it's just an error in the docs. though you should use the [3.0 docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html) , same thing there.

there is no opencv_contrib  or opencv_legacy module anymore in 3.0.

most of its contents (like the face-reco) was [moved](https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/) .